AKS Python Azure Function - console log without timestamp
This is the output of an Azure Function running in a kubernetes pod.
How can I enable the timestamp in my logs?
Can I have one line of log for each message instead of two?
info: Function.name_of_the_function.User[0]
      this is the info message from the function...
info: Function.name_of_the_function.User[0]
      this is the info message from the function...
info: Function.name_of_the_function.User[0]
      this is the info message from the function...
info: Function.name_of_the_function.User[0]
      this is the info message from the function...

Here is my hosts.json
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": "false",
      "DisableColors": true
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "Host": "Warning",
      "Function": "Warning",
      "Function.solr_catalog": "Warning",
      "Function.solr_catalog.User": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "Warning",
      "Azure.Messaging": "Warning",
      "default": "none"
    }
  },


Do you have any host.json configured? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

@AlfredLuu yep, added in the question...

try using Using kubectl raw

@freedev is your issue resolved? Check below my answer for the same.

Azure Functions in Python use the logging module. By default, the Azure Functions runtime adds its own structure to logs, which may cause the output you’re seeing. To ensure proper timestamps and single-line logs, explicitly configure Python's logging module in your function code.
Update your function code as below-
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from datetime import datetime


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Include a timestamp in your log
    timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]

    logging.info(f"{timestamp} - Processing a new request.")

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        logging.info(f"{timestamp} - Successfully processed request for name: {name}.")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        )
    else:
        logging.warning(f"{timestamp} - No name provided in the query string or request body.")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )

took reference from here
Update the host.json to ensure console logging is enabled and that logs are configured correctly
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "DisableColors": true
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function.HttpTrigger": "Information"
    }
  }
}

Update the Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.9

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

Build and push the container image to your container registry
Build and deploy your Function to your acr

inside your aks create a
deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-function-logging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azure-function-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-function-logging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-function-logging
        image: <your-registry>/azure-function-logging:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME
          value: "python"
        - name: AzureWebJobsStorage
          value: "<your-storage-connection-string>"

and a Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-function-logging
spec:
  selector:
    app: azure-function-logging
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer




Now go to your aks and check the logs
kubectl get pods


kubectl logs aks-azure-function-cb7c8b64c-f77tn


Done. Use datetime.utcnow().strftime to include timestamps in every log message.
